# Why does Firefox need a loopback connection?

Tags: linux, firefox, iptables, loopback

I was playing around with firewalls and `iptables`. When I blocked any traffic except HTTP and DNS I was able to establish a connection to `google.com` via `wget google.com`. But I wasn't able to open *google.com* via Firefox.

After a little research I found out that Firefox uses the `loopback device` to communicate with itself ([Firefox loopback connection](http://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/how-stop-firefox-automatically-making-connections#w_loopback-connection)). After I added ACCEPT rules for INPUT and OUTPUT traffic for the loop device, I could open any website via Firefox.

My question is: What exactly does Firefox need the loopback device for?

Comment: I seem to remember it had something to do with parental control. But I'm not sure.

Comment: There is some more information on this topic [here](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=100154).

Comment: I discovered this behaviour while playing around with process explorer, got me triggered for a moment thinking it was malware. I'd like to know more too.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the details, but believe it has something to do with how it implements the Search Bar with possibly multiple search engines as well as it's ability to provide popular search suggestions as you type.